# Best way to change name Sum Sq in anova table

Tags: r

I am changing the Sq sum column in an anova table to present the percentage explained instead.
I have changed the numbers but cannot change the name to Percent. Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Sum Sq` is the second column in the Anova table, which is a `data.frame`.  It can be changed simply with:

```
colnames(df)[2]<-'Percent'
```